# Not able to run if condition in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to run below mentioned script but it giving an error-:

```
last=`grep 'xyz@gmail.com' test | sed 's/"//g'| awk  'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; {    print $8 }' | awk  'BEGIN { FS = " " } ; { print $1 }' | grep $(date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 days ago') | head -1`
d=`(date +%Y-%m-%d --date='3 days ago')`
echo $d--$last
if [ $d == $last ]
 then 
 h=`grep 'xyz@gmail.com' test | wc -l`
 echo $h
 fi
```

The format of file test is -:

```
"xyz@gmail.com","74","PR-460","Mob","one","i.3","2013-11-20 18:12:26","2013-11-21 11:55:33"
"xyz@gmail.com","74","PR-460","Mob","one","i.3","2013-11-20 18:12:26","2013-11-21 11:55:33"
"xyz@gmail.com","74","PR-460","Mob","one","i.3","2013-11-20 18:12:26","2013-11-21 11:55:33"
```

error-:
line 4: [: 2013-11-20: integer expression expected

Comment: What is your `echo` line displaying? Also, what shell are you using--bash?

Comment: By the way, I think you wanted `d=$(date ...)`. The parenthesis inside of the backticks do nothing but make your script less efficient (by creating, and then destroying, an extra subshell).

Comment: ...you should be quoting *everywhere*, by the way, including in your echo statements. So: `echo "$d--$last"`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo

Comment: You might also find http://shellcheck.net/ to be a useful resource.

Comment: ...by the way, `==` isn't actually valid syntax inside of POSIX-standard shells; you should use a single `=` inside your tests unless you're explicitly writing for bash.

Comment: If your grep pipeline is looking for yesterday's date, that will never match the date 3 days ago.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `[[ ]]` (which needs no quotes, and is available in bash, ksh, and zsh), or use `[ ]` and quote your expansions. That is to say, either:

```
# if your script starts with #!/bin/bash
if [[ $d = $last ]]
```

or

```
# if your script starts with #!/bin/sh
if [ "$d" = "$last" ]
```

By the way, `grep | sed | awk` is pretty nasty -- awk can do everything grep and sed can internally.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. It pains me to see long pipelines of grep/sed/awk/head. A single awk call can replace it:

```
last=`grep 'xyz@gmail.com' test | sed 's/"//g'| awk  'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; {    print $8 }' | awk  'BEGIN { FS = " " } ; { print $1 }' | grep $(date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 days ago') | head -1`
```

vs

```
last=$(
    awk -F, -v date=$(date -d yesterday +%F) '
        /xyz@gmail\.com/ {
            gsub(/"/,"")
            split($8, a, / /)
            if (a[1] ~ date) {
                print a[1]
                exit
            }
        }
    ' test
)
```